# Overriding private method

Tags: java, private, overriding

We can not override a private method then why does the followng code does not give an error. Instead it produces the output.

```
class A {
    private void fun() {
        System.out.println("ths is a private method");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void fun() {
        System.out.println("ths is wrng");
    }
}

class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B ob = new B();
        ob.fun();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`private` methods are not inherited. In your `main` method you're invoking the `fun()` method on a variable of type `B`. The `fun()` method of type `B` seems to be accessible, assuming your class `B` and class `C` are in the same package.

Had you done this

```
A ob = new B();
ob.fun();
```

Then you would have gotten your compilation error.

`B#fun()` is completely unrelated to `A#fun()`.

Answer (score 0):

Method `fun()` is not overridden in `B` class because it was never inherited from class `A`.

What you are invoking in your code is method of `B` class and that has no relation with class `A` and method `A#fun()`.

To check this, Add a `@Override` annotation and you will get compile time error.

```
// Compilation error.
Class B extends A{
   @Override
   void fun(){
      System.out.println("ths is wrng");
   }
}
```

Now this code will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Both are completely different methods and not related to each other. As private methods are not inherited there is no concept of overriding here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, private methods are not inherited in child classes. If you still try to write a method with same name as that of parent class, java compiler will consider the method in child class as a completely new method and will not throw any exception. Its like the new method in child class shadows the private method in parent class.